# MVC Attribute not working on individual actions when applied to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, custom-attributes, custom-action-filter

I have an Custom Attribute defined as follows,

```
public class SkipAuthentication : Attribute
{

}
```

and used it to decorate a controller as follows,

```
[SkipAuthentication]
public class AccountTypeController : Controller
{
    // GET: /AccountType/Create
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        try
        {
            return View();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ViewBag.ResMessege = ResMessege.getDanger(ex.Message);
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

now I am expecting that it should get applied to all actions inside controller,

```
public class FebTechFilters : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(SkipAuthentication), false).Any())
        {
            return;
        }

        if (null == filterContext.HttpContext.Session.Contents["UserId"])
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Login/Index");
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

but when I call this, `filterContext.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(SkipAuthentication), false).Any()` I get it as `false` What am I missing?

Comment: Might be that your custom attribute is inheriting from `Attribute` instead of `FilterAttribute`?

Comment: if (filterContext.Controller.GetType().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(SkipAuthentication), false).Any())...

Comment: @NaDeRStar Doesn't ActionDescriptor yields result?

Comment: @DavideVitali Nope, that doesn't work

Comment: But, only ActionFilterAttribute -s will be applied on each action if you add it on controller level, but your SkipAuthentication inherits from Attribute instead of ActionFilterAttribute. And in your code you're not using FebTechFilters, you implemented it, where is it used?